# Rails Active Record Full Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three tables:

```
DataRow (id, user_id)
DataPoint (id, data_row_id, data_type_id)
DataType (id, name, weight)
```

I have the following associations set up:

```
data_row.rb
has_many :data_points

data_point.rb
belongs_to :data_row
belongs_to :data_type
```

In my view, I'd like to display a table with a column for each DataType. My problem is that not every DataRow contains a DataPoint for each DataType.

If I do the below, I'll only get the DataPoints which exist for that DataRow

```
@rows = DataRow.includes(:data_points).where(user_id: params[:id])
```

Is there a way I could return for each user a DataPoint for each DataType for each DataRow, so that I can simply loop through the returned DataRows? The 'weight' column for DataType is the display order.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Could you clarify it? As I see based on your code you only wanna show data for a given user but what you write is the opposite.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. I changed what I wrote to show that I want to show data for a given user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model add this:

**data_row.rb**

```
  has_many :data_points
  has_many :data_types, through: :data_points
```

**data_point.rb**

```
belongs_to :data_row
belongs_to :data_type
```

**data_type.rb**

```
has_many :data_points
has_many :data_rows, through: :data_points
```

You can do `right joins` table.

```
DataRow.select('data_rows.*, data_types.*, data_points.*')
       .joins("RIGHT JOIN data_points ON data_points.data_row_id = data_rows.id
               RIGHT JOIN data_types ON data_types.id = data_points.data_type_id")
```

I hope this help you.